# Which is the best resoulution for Facebook avatar and cover?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, product-design

Which is the best resolution for Facebook avatar and cover in Photoshop because I have tried 300 / 1000 / 1500, but it looks horrible, please give me the exact HD resolution for each.

Comment: Welcome to GD!  1)Please don't use foul language in your questions. 2)Facebook is for the web so Im not sure why you tagged this as [tag:print-production]?  If there is a reason why can you explain that by editing your question?  Same question applies for [tag:product-design].  If there is a reason why you are tagging it in that manner please edit your question.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots. And when you say 300/1000/1500, what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

Cover photo is 851px x 315px

Profile photo is recommended to be uploaded at 180 px x 180 px but is displayed at 160px x 160px

It's all of course 72ppi since its online usage.

A handy page for this is: https://www.facebook.com/CoverPhotoSize

The official facebook page with much of this information and more is: [https://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=cover+guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=cover%20guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is 72ppi, as any normal image prepared for the web (ignoring retina display screens).

That being said, if you look through Facebook's recommendations, you'll see that the basics are the following:

- Image in PNG format
- sRGB colour profile
- Image should be less than 99Kb

I did this for the covers for my Facebook pages with excellent results.

Answer (score -2):

The Facebook cover has a lot of different sizes, for example if you want to use it for a business page you must do a 820x312px cover at 72 dpi. For smart phone 640x360px at 300 dpi.